# negation of math statement in English

Tags: logic

I am a bit confused of the negation of this statement:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$ such that
>   $f(a) = f(b)$, then there is at least one number $c$ in the open interval
>   $(a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

I know the implication $p \Rightarrow q$ should negated as $\neg q \land p$, so I will need to negate the second part of the sentence. My question is that should I negate the phrase "open interval"? or should it be "there isn't any number $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$" ?

Comment: Your second proposal is indeed correct

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the negation of “$\exists c:P(c)$” is ”$\forall c:\lnot P(c)$” therefore the negation should be: “for all $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ we have  $f'(c) \neq  0$”.